# How to stack certain columns into one based on several columns

Tags: google-sheets

We use google forms to gather data for actions on different problems. This is then routed to google sheets for monitoring of actions identified.

I created a trial file to show the input and the expected output, which can be viewed [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ewVtjJPzImQFdusa9OzcY62csYcbTUx7Nb6vthNLzg/edit?usp=sharing).

So in here, the Problem, actions, assigned person and timelines will need to be stacked together based on team and activity as shown in the file. I tried to combine the QUERY function with other functions, but still to no avail.

I previously asked about this but with a simpler data set, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593375/stack-multiple-columns-in-a-single-column-based-on-another-column/66595546?noredirect=1#comment117759285_66595546). Now, after several days of brain-twisting to expand this to a more complex data set, I realized that I should have asked based on an exact representation of the data, and not a simple one *(I got confident, but didn't realize it was in fact pretty hard - quite a lessons learned from my end)*.

Again, hoping for your guidance on how this can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an elegant answer to this - my solution is very clunky. It's based on the idea of using Sequence to generate the right number of rows for the output, then doing a Vlookup in the rolling count of number of entries per row (using Countifs).

The formula for the first two columns is:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(iferror(vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),
{query(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,"select Col1"),A2:A&"|"&B2:B},2,false),"|"),"|",,false))
```

And for column 3:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),{if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),C2:N},
2+(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0)
-vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),1,true))*4,true))
```

Column 4 is

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),{if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),C2:N},
3+(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0)
-vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),1,true))*4,true))
```

and you have to change 3 to 4 for the next column.

The last column includes to_date:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),{if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),C2:N},
5+(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0)
-vlookup(SEQUENCE(counta(C2:N)/4,1,0),if(A2:A<>"",index(countifs(if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)),"<"&if(C2:N<>"",row(C2:N)))/4,0,1),),1,true))*4,true)))
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate the effort you've done for this. Thanks so much!